# Taking screenshots on failure using Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am new to robot framework. I want to know how to capture screenshots on failure.
Doesnt robot framework automatically take screenshots if script fails?
An example will be of great help!

Comment: I believe that it done automatically on failure. Isn't it the case?

Answer (score 8):

this is actually a feature of the Selenium2Library that would be required with Robot if you were doing Selenium based tests.

More information can be found here: http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html

As it says it the documentation, setting up screenshots on failure is very easy, for example here is mine from a test suite I'm working with:

```
Library    Selenium2Library  timeout=10   implicit_wait=1.5   run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot
```

Comment: "Take Screenshot With Timestamp" keyword not found

Comment: Apologies Sveatoslav, I did't pick this up that it was a custom keyword when I answered originally.  I've replaced the keyword with a keyword found in the Selenium2Library by default.  Thanks for calling it out!

Comment: No worries, can you post the custom one as well?

Comment: sorry Sveatoslav, I don't know which application it is from so don't have access to it.  In saying that from the name, I imagine it was simply taking the screenshot and printing a timestamp to the console.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a custom screenshots name with the time-stamps

Comment: I honestly couldn't say I'm afraid but if I come across it again, I'll add it in here

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below keyword to capture screen shot after any of the step you want :

```
Capture Page Screenshot
```

Hope so this was helpful!

Comment: That would require the "poor guy" to add that Keyword below any single keyword in his test.. really not efficient, but it would work :-D

Answer (score 1):

So far, all of the other answers assume that you are using Selenium

If you are not, there is a "Screenshot" library that has the keyword "Take Screenshot." To include this library, all you need to do is put "Library    Screenshot" in your settings table.

In my robotframework code, my teardowns all just reference a keyword I made called "Default Teardown" which is defined as:

```
Default Teardown
    Run Keyword If Test Failed    Take Screenshot
    Close All
```

(I think that the Close All might be one of my custom keywords).

I have noticed a few issues with the Take Screenshot keyword. Some of this may be configurable, but I don't know. First off, it will take a screenshot of your screen, not necessarily just the application that you are interested in. So if you're using this and are allowing other people to view the resulting screenshots, make sure that you don't have anything else on your screen that you wouldn't want to share.

Also, if you kick off your tests and then lock your screen so you can take a quick break while it runs, all of your screenshots will just be pictures of your lock screen.

I'm using this on my Jenkins server as well which is using the xvfb-run command to create sort of a fake GUI to run the robot framework tests. If you're doing this as well, make sure that in your xvfb-run command you include something along the lines of

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" <rest of your command>
```

You'll have to decide what screen resolution works the best for you, but I found that with the default screen resolution, only a small portion of my app was captured.

Long story short, I think that you're better off using Capture Page Screenshot if you're using selenium. However if you're not, this may be your best (or only) solution.

Answer (score 0):

In this case teardown will be executed once the test case is executed/not executed and if the test case fail, it will take screenshot:

```
[Teardown]    Run Keyword If Test Failed    Capture Page Screenshot
```

Or you can do it even better on suite level if you don't need different teardowns for particular tests:

```
[Test Teardown]    Run Keyword If Test Failed    Capture Page Screenshot
```